# I.Robot 7180 ICS OS4.0 tablet stucked loading in the black screen with android logo showing. How to make this work again?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My I.Robot 7180 ICS OS4.0 tablet was drained, when charged i tried to open it again but it was only stucked loading in the black screen with android logo showing. How to make this work again?